# How do i set a remote ssh connection and mount directory in ubuntu 10.04 over the internet?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-10.04, nfs, openssh

Can any on help me with setting a remote ssh connection and NFS (or any other way to mount a directory from the server on my ubuntu client) over the internet?

All the manuals i found where talking about local networking and i can't find any thing that will help me to understand the way to set it over the web...

I have and Ubuntu lucid server in my NAT and apache2 server installed and working. what i need is a way to mount the "www" directory also when i am not inside the NAT so i could work over the internet.

So i guess i need two things. how do i connect to the server with ssh and how do i use NFS or wny things else to mount directories on my client Ububntu lucid over the web.

Thank you very much,
Erez

Comment: you should probably read some basic literature on networking and socket servers and come back again if you are still having problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a question that should rather go to superuser or ubuntuusers but here you go.

just open nautilus (the default file manager) and go to file -> connect to server.

then enter the type (ftp/ssh/samba and many others are supported) and credentials.

you will be able to work directly with the files. all sorts of permissions etc are supported as far as the protocol does.

the fuse module is used to mount it under user space.

edit:

another way (that is probably suited better in server environments) is to use sshfs. it doesnt come default but can easily be installed over the repositories.
but i'd rather recommend setting up nfs (altough its security management is quite controversial and its very old its very robust and achieves good performance).
there are loads of tutorials available.

Comment: Thank you joe, but as i said, all the tutorials i found are fot local networks, Didn't find any for ones that deal with over the internet....but i will look for it in super user, thank you very much :-)

Comment: theres no difference between local network and internet on the ssh protocol.

Comment: well, joe, after few hours of trying, i guess there is some didderence, on my local network i can connect to the eclipse PyDev project and work on the server, with the remote connection, never mind what i try and do, the eclipse just doesn't seem to wont to find the server over sftp...seem like the ide doesn't know what is sftp and doesn't "see" the mount....am i wrong?

Comment: its only displayed this way. if you look into `/home/your-username/.gvfs` you will see a directory where your location is mounted. you can also just type mount into the terminal and you see a mount by the fuse deamon. in this directory your remote filesystems are mounted, and there you can access them via local paths cope,.

Comment: thanks Joe, i wen't with e diferent aproch thou, it's for my designer for now, so i did it with the aptana and not the PyDev and the Aptanas ftps connect with no problems, and every thing is working great, but it is good to know :-)

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to configure your NAT router to forward `ssh` or `sftp` or `nfs` or `git` or `rsync` connections to your internal machine in addition to `http`.

How you do that depends upon your router. (Be careful forwarding, your firewall currently provides some level of protection from the big bad internet. When you forward connections to your server, be sure you know how to configure the forwarded service safely.)

You might also wish to look into [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/) as a mechanism to synchronize files between multiple machines. I've not yet used it, but it looks slick, and avoids many problems with port forwarding connections to internal systems, if the internal systems can be configured to pull data in from outside easily.